# LLVM/Clang generating useless-looking instructions

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, x86-64, llvm-clang

If I write this code:

```
void loop1(int N, double* R, double* A, double* B) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) {
        R[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
}
```

Clang (`-O3`) generates the following x64 ASM as part of an unrolled version of the loop ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KpUofx)):

```
.LBB0_14:
    movupd  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdx + 8*rax]
    movupd  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdx + 8*rax + 16]
    movupd  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax]
    addpd   xmm2, xmm0
    movupd  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax + 16]
    addpd   xmm0, xmm1
    movupd  xmmword ptr [rsi + 8*rax], xmm2
    movupd  xmmword ptr [rsi + 8*rax + 16], xmm0
```

`rdx` and `rcx` are holding my input pointers (`A`/`B`), `rsi` is the output (`R`), and `rax` is an offset counter.  So it's loading two pairs of inputs/outputs at a time, adding them using SIMD instructions, and writing them to the output - so far so good.

If instead I write the following:

```
void loop2(int N, double* R, double* A, double* B) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 2) {
        R[i] = A[i] + B[i];
        R[i + 1] = A[i + 1] + B[i + 1];
    }
}
```

LLVM generates the following ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/riDoef)):

```
.LBB0_13:
    movupd  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdx + 8*rdi]
    movupd  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdx + 8*rdi + 16]
    movupd  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rdi]
    addpd   xmm2, xmm0
    movupd  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rdi + 16]
    addpd   xmm0, xmm1

    movapd  xmm1, xmm2
    unpckhpd        xmm1, xmm0      # xmm1 = xmm1[1],xmm0[1]
    unpcklpd        xmm2, xmm0      # xmm2 = xmm2[0],xmm0[0]
    movapd  xmm0, xmm2
    unpcklpd        xmm0, xmm1      # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0]
    unpckhpd        xmm2, xmm1      # xmm2 = xmm2[1],xmm1[1]

    movupd  xmmword ptr [rsi + 8*rdi + 16], xmm2
    movupd  xmmword ptr [rsi + 8*rdi], xmm0
```

Spacing added for clarity, because it's that middle section with the `unpckhpd` etc. that's confusing me.  As far as I can see, the overall effect of those 6 instructions is just to swap `xmm0` and `xmm2`, which seems like a waste of time.

Any idea why it's doing this?  And is there a way to stop it? :p

---

*EDIT*: I edited the ASM for `loop2()` to remove all similar blocks (and swap around the registers in the subsequent writes), and it appeared to run correctly and the same speed as `loop1()` (~40% faster)

Comment: You could conceivably simply generate the assembly, compile it with an assembler, and see if removing these instructions have any effect?

Comment: Yup, looks like a missed optimization.  Apparently manual unrolling confused / interfered with the automatic unrolling that happens as part of auto-vectorization and you ended up with a mess.  Report it at https://bugs.llvm.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=new-bugs.  It's a nice clean very minimal MCVE, and the bug happens even with `__restrict` on all 3 pointers.  (But that does get LLVM not to check for overlap at runtime, or emit a scalar version of the loop for that case.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: As an aside, is LLVM/Clang assuming `R` does not overlap `A` or `B`? Why is it allowed to do that without a `restrict` qualifier?

Comment: @EricPostpischil part of the stuff at `.LBB0_8` checks for that, those `lea` compute the end addresses and then the ranges are compared for overlap